# Rearrange file based on first field

Tags: awk, sed, files

I  Have a file with contents like in sample input, want to rearrange as in required output. Unsure how to achieve with sed and awk with this.

**Sample Input**

```
bni                           bce_merge_bni
bni                           def_merge_bni
bni                           linus_merge_bni
bni                           cat_merge_bni
bni                           ten_merge_bni
bni                           kit_merge_bni
us-canada              chix_merge_usgenuity
us-canada              cavin_merge_usgenuity
us-canada              miuns_merge_usgenuity
us-canada              ate_merge_usgenuity
us-canada              eat_merge_usgenuity
```

***Required Output***

```
bni abc_merge_bni bce_merge_bni def_merge_bni linus_merge_bni  cat_merge_bni ten_merge_bni kit_merge_bni
us-canada chix_merge_usgenuity cavin_merge_usgenuity  miuns_merge_usgenuity ate_merge_usgenuity eat_merge_usgenuity
```